# Concatenate a value to an existing xml attribute using XMLStarlet (Image Annotation)

Tags: xml, bash, annotations, xmlstarlet

I am working on annotating images using xml. I am using xmlstarlet and unix bash commands but I am facing some issues when I try to append a value to an existing xml attribute value. For example, I have `<filename>a</filename>` and I want to make it `<filename>a.jpg</filename>` (i.e. concatenate '.jpg' to the existing value).

I used the following piece of code but it totally overwrites the value (i.e. `<filename>.jpg</filename>`.

Script:

```
for name in *.xml; do xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u '/annotation/filename' -v .jpg "$name"; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`xmlstarlet`** solution:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -u '//annotation/filename' -x 'concat(., ".jpg")' input.xml
```

---

Quick guide: `xmlstarlet ed --help`