# Append text to xml tag value

Tags: python, xml, sed

I would like to add a text to the end of "NAME" value in "INCOND" tag in below xml lines.

```
<System>
    <FOLDER FOLDER_NAME="Production" >
        <JOB JOBNAME="JOB1" >
            <INCOND NAME="First-Cond-PROD" ODATE="ODAT" />
        </JOB>
        <JOB JOBNAME="JOB1" >
            <INCOND NAME="Second-Cond-PROD" ODATE="ODAT" />
        </JOB>
        <JOB JOBNAME="JOB1" >
            <INCOND NAME="Third-Cond-PROD" ODATE="ODAT" />
        </JOB>
    </FOLDER>
</System>
```

I've looked at xml ed, sed examples but those help in replacing the values. Since the values are not constant across 3K entries that I got to modify, the one I referred do not help. The desired output I am looking at is like below:

```
<System>
    <FOLDER FOLDER_NAME="Production" >
        <JOB JOBNAME="JOB1" >
            <INCOND NAME="First-Cond-PROD-DR" />
        </JOB>
        <JOB JOBNAME="JOB1" >
            <INCOND NAME="Second-Cond-PROD-DR" />
        </JOB>
        <JOB JOBNAME="JOB1" >
            <INCOND NAME="Third-Cond-PROD-DR" />
        </JOB>
    </FOLDER>
</System>
```

Can you please help me with a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate a value to an existing xml attribute using XMLStarlet (Image Annotation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48904096/concatenate-a-value-to-an-existing-xml-attribute-using-xmlstarlet-image-annotat) <= just change this command to use your values :)

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ sed 's/\(<INCOND.*\)"/\1-DR"/' file
<System>
    <FOLDER FOLDER_NAME="Production" >
        <JOB JOBNAME="JOB1" >
            <INCOND NAME="First-Cond-PROD-DR" />
        </JOB>
        <JOB JOBNAME="JOB1" >
            <INCOND NAME="Second-Cond-PROD-DR" />
        </JOB>
        <JOB JOBNAME="JOB1" >
            <INCOND NAME="Third-Cond-PROD-DR" />
        </JOB>
    </FOLDER>
</System>
```

Comment: It worked partially, but I had posted the shorter version of the code, my bad. There are two values inside INCOND tag, using your expr it gave below:

<System>
    <FOLDER FOLDER_NAME="Production" >
        <JOB JOBNAME="JOB1" >
            <INCOND NAME="First-Cond-PROD" ODATE="ODAT-DR" />
        </JOB>
        <JOB JOBNAME="JOB1" >
            <INCOND NAME="Second-Cond-PROD" ODATE="ODAT-DR" />
        </JOB>
        <JOB JOBNAME="JOB1" >
            <INCOND NAME="Third-Cond-PROD" ODATE="ODAT-DR" />
        </JOB>
    </FOLDER>
</System>


How to append '-DR' to NAME value ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your question tagged python, here's an option using lxml...

**Python 3.6**

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

for attr in tree.xpath("//INCOND/@NAME"):
    attr.getparent().attrib["NAME"] = f"{attr}-DR"

print(etree.tostring(tree, encoding="unicode"))
```

**Output**

```
<System>
    <FOLDER FOLDER_NAME="Production">
        <JOB JOBNAME="JOB1">
            <INCOND NAME="First-Cond-PROD-DR" ODATE="ODAT"/>
        </JOB>
        <JOB JOBNAME="JOB1">
            <INCOND NAME="Second-Cond-PROD-DR" ODATE="ODAT"/>
        </JOB>
        <JOB JOBNAME="JOB1">
            <INCOND NAME="Third-Cond-PROD-DR" ODATE="ODAT"/>
        </JOB>
    </FOLDER>
</System>
```

I prefer lxml over ElementTree because of better xpath support, but ElementTree is another option (same output as above)...

**Python 3.6**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

for elem in tree.findall(".//INCOND[@NAME]"):
    elem.set("NAME", f"{elem.get('NAME')}-DR")

print(etree.tostring(tree.getroot(), encoding="unicode"))
```

You could also use xmlstarlet (same output as above)...

**xmlstarlet command line**

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//INCOND/@NAME' -x 'concat(.,"-DR")' input.xml
```